# Proper exception list for iPhone - Android etc theme

Tags: theme

I am using this list for our iPhone theme

iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

We see the theme when viewing from a testing site (Virtual phone) but when I look at it on a real phone we are getting the default theme? We are using Saucelabs.com for testing.

Comment: It appears that I am not accounting for the retina display :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my mobile screen size: Here is an example.

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
```

For a retnis device it will look for a different css class and thus the default Magento background

Answer (score 0):

Just put a simple script on your server with this  code

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

and call it from your mobile device. Whatever is shown is what you need to add to your exception list. Also check your phone settings. Mine, for example, has an option to disable the mobile views of websites. Most probably it sends a different user again in this case.